# How can I modify Notepad++ here delim?

Tags: bash, notepad++

I want to document bash scripts with perl pod comments, as explained [here](http://bahut.alma.ch/2007/08/embedding-documentation-in-shell-script_16.html).

```
cat<<=cut
perlpod
=cut
```

Unfortunately, notepad++ does not consider the `=` character as being part of the here delim, resulting in unusable syntax highlighting.

How can I change the definition of the here delim?

I looked at UDL but I'd rather change the existing bash definition than redefine it from scratch. If changing UDL is the way, then where can I find the default bash UDL?

Comment: The most common delimiter for heredoc is `EOF`. `=cut` is pretty insane.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you import the default bash in the "Language > Define Your Language..." and change the HERE DELIM default keywords you will be able to add the "=" sign there.

I have not tried this myself to be honest but that is a possible way of doing it.